# PHP split to preg_split()

Tags: php, regex, split, preg-split

I wanted to convert the following split function, which I have been using to preg_split.. it's a little confusing, because the value will change from time to time...

Current code:

```
$root_dir = 'www';
$current_dir = 'D:/Projects/job.com/www/www/path/source';
$array = split('www', 'D:/Projects/job.com/www/www/path/source', 2);
print_r($array);
```

Output of the split function:

```
Array ( [0] => D:/Projects/job.com/ [1] => /www/path/source )
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `preg_split`?

Comment: is `split` just a function that uses `preg_split` ? and why don't you use explode ?

Comment: @RobertPitt: `split()` is an old, deprecated function that didn't use PCRE at all, but a different regex engine/syntax.

Comment: Ahh, I've just looked it up on PHP, never used such a function before.

Comment: i have function that build path, so i can easily use it in linux or windows or any platform, without worrying, about anything..

Comment: hmmm, theres better tools in the box for jobs like this. look at `PHP_OS`,`__DIR__`,`__FILE__`,`dirname`,`basename`,`realpath` if you want to discover directory patter for the OS

Answer (score 21, accepted):

preg_split() is similar to the old ereg-function split(). You only have to enclose the regex in `/.../` like so:

```
preg_split('/www/', 'D:/Projects/job.com/www/www/path/source', 2);
```

The enclosing slashes `/` here are really part of the regular expression syntax, not searched for in the string. If the `www` delimiter is variable, you should additionally use preg_quote() for the inner part.

But note that you don't need regular expressions if you only look for static strings anyway. In such cases you can use `explode()` pretty much like you used split() before:

```
explode('www', 'D:/Projects/job.com/www/www/path/source', 2);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i cant accept it, because its giving me massage, that i can accept after 2 mins.. but it work, thanks

Comment: btw isnt preg_split is faster then explode?

Comment: @Basit: Not usually. Explode does a simple binary search, and doesn't have to look for complex/optional patterns. Also it's implemented as core PHP function, thus can deal with PHP strings better and generate a PHP array directly. The preg_split() function is slower because it makes a roundtrip over libPCRE.  -- So explode() is always faster. (Regular expression matching with preg_match() OTOH can often be more efficient than simple PHP string function arithmetics.)

Comment: @Basit Just think of the work regex has to do compared to simply splitting a string by a particular keyword, it's obvious `explode()` should be faster!